# Entity Framework saveChanges does not work with some entities

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have this db structure:

```
User
Company
CompanyUser
```

CompanyUser has a `UserId` and `CompanyId` column and a boolean.

User entity has this navigation item:

```
ICollection<CompanyUser> Companies
```

Company has this a navigation item:

```
ICollection<CompanyUser> Users
```

CompanyUser looks like this:

```
public class CompanyUser : BaseEntity
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets if the user is an admin
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// gets or sets the company id
    /// </summary>
    public Guid? CompanyId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// gets or set the user id
    /// </summary>
    public Guid? UserId { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }       
}
```

I can create a `User` and a `Company` entities and they insert into the database. But when I create a `CompanyUser` like so it does not insert at all.

```
User user = new User();
// Set properties
_userService.InsertUser(user);

Company company = _companyService.GetCompanyById(i);
CompanyUser companyUser = new CompanyUser()
{
    IsAdmin = true,
    CompanyId = company.Id,
    UserId = user.Id
};

_companyService.InsertCompanyUser(companyUser);
```

I cannot understand why this does not insert. I have debugged it and there are no exceptions being thrown or caught that I don't know about. When I view what companyUser contains it looks exactly perfect.

`SaveChanges()` returns `0` with every `CompanyUser` change and the `Entities'` count is always `0`

This entity framework has been throwing me around for the past few hours and I can't seem to figure this one out. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Here is the `InsertCompanyUser`

```
try
{
    if (entity == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");

    this.Entities.Add(entity); 
    this._context.SaveChanges();
}
```

`this.Entities` is an `IDbSet<T>`

My DB Context extends DBContext and has this method:

```
public new IDbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : BaseEntity
{
    return base.Set<TEntity>();
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

The `DbSet` for `CompanyUser` always retains a count of 0 and never increases but `Company` and `User` `DbSet`s are increasing as they should. Why would DbSet not increase when calling `Add`

Comment: I don't think you have to set both the Company and the CompanyId and both the User and UserId. Just set the foreign key values for the insert and set if it gets saved.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that. I have tried setting just the navigational properties too and that went no where.

Comment: What does your context class look like?

Comment: I updated my question to have info about the context and insert method

Comment: I'm wondering if it has something to do with the `Key` attributes on your `CompanyUser` entity? I'm guessing you're defining `Id` in `BaseEntity` so could it be throwing it off when EF finds Id as primary key and finds `CompanyId` and `UserId` as composite keys? What happens if you remove the `Key` attributes completely from `UserId` and `CompanyId`?

Comment: I changed my mapping on `CompanyUser` to `Ignore` the Id that is on `BaseEntity`. And Changed the Key to `HasKey(cp => new { cp.CompanyId, cp.UserId });` I will try and remove the `Key` attributes

Comment: Hmm, that sounds correct for setting up a composite key. Don't think it's the issue but you shouldn't need to do that both in annotations and the fluent api.

Comment: So I removed the [Key] and rebuilt the database and it's still having the same issue.

Comment: Yea I didn't expected it to work after you said you were Ignoring Id. Everything looks okay to me. Are you sure `InsertCompanyUser` adds the item to the `DbSet`? Are you sure you're grabbing the `CompanyUser` `DbSet` from your context's `Set<T>` method?

Comment: I'm experimenting weird behavior with EF too. Not sure it it's related but *just in case* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24375846/updated-objectcontext-to-entity-framework-6-works-way-too-different-with-naviga

Comment: @Smith.h.Neil So it looks like the count on Entities does not increase for `CompanyUser` but does for the other entities. Why would it not be adding correctly?

Comment: @Brenjt Not sure. Step through line by line. You're not passing in a `null` and catching `ArgumentNullException` are you? That could cause it to silently fail.

Comment: No, I stepped all the way through and the entity was exactly how it should have been down to the save method. Is there any way you can help me debug this? Over screenshare or in chat? I have tried everything I know how to do?

Comment: I might have some free time after work tonight where I could help. Start a chat later today if you don't get anywhere with this.

Comment: So its working now. I renamed my Navigational properties to be `CompanyUser` and changed my Mapping table to be `Company_User_Mapping` rather than `CompanyUser`. Then changed my mapping to `this.HasRequired(cu => cu.User).WithMany(u => u.CompanyUsers).HasForeignKey(cu => cu.UserId);` and ` this.HasRequired(cu => cu.Company).WithMany(c => c.CompanyUsers).HasForeignKey(cu => cu.CompanyId);` on just the CompanyUser removing the other mapping on the `Company` & `User` entities.

Answer (score 1):

Check your object model is generating tables that are correctly related using primary / foreign keys, then try this approach:

```
User user = new User();
// Set properties

Company company = _context.Companies.Find(i);
CompanyUser companyUser = new CompanyUser()
{
    IsAdmin = true,
    User = user
};

company.Users.Add(companyUser);
_context.SaveChanges();
```