# Updated ObjectContext to Entity Framework 6. Works way too different with navigation properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I was using .EDMX file version 2, using legacy ObjectContext.

I updated to codestrategy T4, and updated references and config files for Entity Framework 6.2

I'm using LazyLoadingEnabled = true (before and after the upgrade);

Old objectcontext :

```
ret = new PropertySet {
    display_name = DisplayName,
    id_product = IdProduct // this is a foreign key to the entity Product
};
context.PropertySets.Add(ret);
context.SaveChanges();
// calling ret.Product returns the product object with all properties filled.
```

New DbContext :

```
ret = new PropertySet {
    display_name = DisplayName,
    id_product = IdProduct // this is a foreign key to the entity Product
};
context.PropertySets.Add(ret);
context.SaveChanges();
// calling ret.Product returns null. (HERE IS THE PROBLEM)
// calling context.Entry(ret).Product.Load() loads the correct Product.
```

I'm worried about this 'new' behavior because it breaks existing code, with runtime error. This is a big app and we don't have tests against EF.

I'm wondering if there's is some option or something that's wrong or it is just a new way of doing things? Am I missing something ?

Thanks, I really appreciate any clue, I was looking around all day, since lots of bugs has been introduced to the app because of this different behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't just upgrade, you changed from ObjectContext to DbContext.  This also means changing from to DbSet.  These behave differently, because DbContext is intended to simplify things.

The problem is that ObjectContext defaulted to using Self Tracking Entities (STE's), which have been deprecated and are no longer officially supported in EF6 (you can, however, download the STE templates from EF5 and try to adapt them to EF6).

PS, your property names violate standard EF naming conventions, which means you don't get much of the benefit of convention over configuration.  ie, you are forced to configure things you shouldn't have to.

If this is your only problem, then there are some workarounds.. if it's not, you may want to invest in trying to adapt the EF5 t4 templates for STE's.

There's an article here about using STE's http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj613941

For a workaround, you can add the Reload() method like you've done, or you can create a proxied entity like this:

```
ret = context.PropertySets.Create();  // creates proxied entity
ret.display_name = DisplayName;
ret.id_product = IdProduct // this is a foreign key to the entity Product

context.PropertySets.Add(ret);
context.SaveChanges();

var name = ret.Product.Name; // should now work.
```

Either way, you're going to have make code changes if you want to use EF6.  The question is, where do you want to do it?

Comment: Yes, this is my only problem. Even I'm not using EF naming conventions (MySQL database), I'm doing Database First which have the foreign key and using the EF 6 DbContext generator did all the code for me. Do you think I can enter into some other 'problems' ? Trying the proxy thing now.

Comment: Yes, doing context.PropertySets.Create() does work. I see that I have to context.PropertySets.Add() it to the context either way. What exactly does this Create() ? If I don't know if the property exists can I use Create() and then ret = context.PropertySets.Find() and if null fill the values ? How is the workflow in DbContext ? I'm very familiar with ObjectContext and this is 'disruptive' on my code :(

Comment: @Bart - EF tracks changes in entities through something called the `ObjectStateManager`, and by default it wraps entities in a "proxy" class that detects when changes are made.  When you use `new` to create the object, the ObjectStateManager doesn't know anything about this class, because it hasn't been wrapped in a proxy.  When you use Create, it creates an entity and wraps it in the change tracking proxy.  This proxy is what does the lazy loading on virtual methods and collections.

Comment: @Bart - I'm not sure what you mean by "not knowing" if the property exists, do you mean you don't know if the row exists?  You don't need to use Create if you're using Find, since Find returns a proxied PropertySet already, it should already be hooked up.  If you fill in an ID after the find, then call SaveChanges, then EF will save the modified record with your new id_product.

Comment: @Funkenbusch So in theory if I change all my 'new entity' statements to Create() everything should work. Is there any way to attach this "proxy" on the class constructor somehow? I'm evaluating the amount of code to update.

Comment: @Bart - The create creates a new instance, so that would result in a recursive loop that would cause a stack overflow.  Each new instance would call the constructor which would call create which would call the constructor... etc. etc..